# Drupal 8 API rest menu items not showing for anonymous users

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have a create a basic page node with url alias as "/support/overview". And added in the menu navigation as menu item. I am using the `rest_menu_item module`, to generate the json. http://localhost/drupal8/api/menu_items/main-navigation, the added url alias in the menu item not showing for the anonymous user. Could you please help on this!